# ddrescue read non tried blocks

Tags: recovery, file-recovery

I'm trying to rescue a 1TB disk which has read errors. Because I didn't have a free 1TB drive, I created a raid 0 of two 500GB drives.
I used the command line from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue) for the first run:

```
sudo ddrescue -f -n /dev/sdk /dev/md/md_test /home/user/rescue.map
```

ddrescue already completed this run after approximately 20 hours and more than 7000 read errors.
Now I'm trying to do a second run

```
sudo ddrescue -d -f -v -r3 /dev/sdk /dev/md/md_test /home/user/rescue.map
```

and read the non tried blocks but ddrescue gives me this:

```
GNU ddrescue 1.23
About to copy 1000 GBytes from '/dev/sdk' to '/dev/md/md_test'
Starting positions: infile = 0 B,  outfile = 0 B
Copy block size: 128 sectors       Initial skip size: 19584 sectors
Sector size: 512 Bytes

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from mapfile)
rescued: 635060 MB, tried: 0 B, bad-sector: 0 B, bad areas: 0

Current status
 ipos:    1000 GB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
 opos:    1000 GB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
 non-tried:  365109 MB,  bad-sector:   0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
 rescued:  635060 MB,   bad areas:     0,        run time:          0s
 pct rescued:   63.49%, read errors:   0,  remaining time:         n/a
                          time since last successful read:         n/a
 Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)
 ddrescue: Write error: Invalid argument
```

I can't figure out what this write errors means, already searched the manual for answers.
Any help is appreciated! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found the cause for the write error, the capacity of the corrupt drive is 931,5G but the total capacity of the raid 0 was just 931,**3**G.
Realized it, while I took a closer look to the output of *lsblk* command.

So I rebuild the raid 0 array with 3 500G drives and ddrescue now works as expected.